# Ordenar radiobuttons ocultos em stackpanel WPF

Tags: vb.net, wpf

Tenho uma stackpanel com vários radiobuttons nela, dependendo da entrada do usuário alguns desses
radiobuttons ficam ocultos (propriedade visibility = visibility.hidden). Eu gostaria que conforme isso acontece, o stackpanel (ou outro componente) organize os radiobuttons de forma que os visíveis vão para cima da listagem e os ocultos fiquem para baixo. O que acontece atualmente é que eu oculto os radiobuttons, mas mesmo ocultos eles continuam no top da listagem, fazendo com que os visíveis fiquem embaixo.

```
    For Each item As RadioButton In spItens.Children
        If Not item.Content.ToString.Contains(txtBusca.Text) Then
            item.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
        ElseIf txtBusca.Text = "" Then
            item.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia Fernando, você vai ter que criar uma Array com a posição de cada radiobutton

```
Dim Posicoes As Point() = {RadioButton1.Margin, RadioButton2.Margin, RadioButton3.Margin} 
' Precisam estar em ordem
```

Dai na sua função você teria que chamar a Array em Ordem, da seguinte maneira

```
Dim n As Integer
        For Each item As RadioButton In spItens.Children
            If Not item.Content.ToString.Contains(txtBusca.Text) Then
                item.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
            ElseIf txtBusca.Text = "" Then
                item.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
                item.Margin= Posicoes(n) ' Mover o item para a posição
                n += 1 ' Pular para a segunda posição e assim por diante
            End If
        Next
```

Ou seja, o valor de "n" só será incrementado quando for um comando que é pra estar visível...

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas não achei a propriedade 'Location' no radiobutton.

Comment: Então @FernandoFragoso, isso está meio estranho porque eu não reconheço essa propriedade "Visibility", apenas "Visible", mas de qualquer maneira,quando você entra nas propriedades do controle, não tem algo parecido com "Location"? Um campo que contém os valores "X" e "Y"?

Comment: Não tem. Lembrando que estou fazendo em WPF, que difere um pouco do VB.NET windows forms.

Comment: @FernandoFragoso Entendi, olhei na internet aqui e a propriedade "Location" em WPF é a mesma que "Margin", fiz a alteração na resposta original, da uma olhada pra vê se agora vai dar certo...

Comment: @FernandoFragoso Deu certo?